# How to get event that user entered app info page of current app in android

Tags: android, mobile

I'm going to user can't uninstall app. My app is service app so there is no icon in screen.
User can only uninstall in settings/appinfo page.
So I'm going to redirect to home screen when user get into app's info page.
I need to get event that user get into app's info page.

I tried to like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVgtF.png)
`enter code here`
then this not working.
How can I do to solve this?
Please help me.

Comment: AFAIK the android system doesn't allow to do that... Probably system apps can benefit in this case

Comment: But I saw that app when user enter to app info page, it redirects to home screen.

Comment: Have you discussed your plans with an attorney?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this.  It would be horribly insecure if you could- tailor made for malware.  The way you can prevent uninstallation is using device owner policies, but that's not available for a normal app.

Comment: This is no my app. My clients app. And this is really impossilbe? My clinet showed me sample app, and i checked it. Then it works just like this feature.

Comment: I think maybe your wording was awkward, I just reread your post.  Do you want your app's main activity to redirect to the settings page?  Or do you want its page in the applications menu to go to your main activity?  The first is possible, the second isn't

Comment: I solved this issue by myself. thanks for your replying.

Comment: @RildoPaul how do you solve it?