# How can redirect app info page in settings

Tags: android, settings

Same as this question [How to get event that user entered app info page of current app in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69050209/how-to-get-event-that-user-entered-app-info-page-of-current-app-in-android)

I saw a video for someone he did acode for redirect to home screen when he clicked on app info page in setting and can't access to app info from anywhere.but he didn't publish how he did it. Is there a manifest code or edit something in apk file ?

I didn't try anything because i don't know how he did it .

Comment: You want to open an screen from your app when the user access the info screen of your app?

Comment: Yes redirect from the app info in settings to home screen so i don't want the user to access the app info in settings

Comment: Im pretty sure that you can not code such thing. You don't have the video you are mentioned? And do you know if it is a root device?

Comment: Yes i have the video but i have no idea if it rooted device or not

Comment: Can I see this video?